# Displaying a video as loop upfront to an InVision Prototype on an iPad (iFrame? Forwarding?)

Tags: html, iframe, prototyping

My basic problem: Having an html5 video (or else, just needs to be a video) played in a loop on an iPad Device. As soon as someone touches it, an InVision Prototype should be displayed.

In addition the loading time of the InVision Prototype should be as fast as possible (in the best case the user does not even recognize it's InVision).

What i learned so far:

1. InVision does not allow Videos.
2. Loading InVision in an iFrame and displaying the Video above it until it was clicked, does not work out, since InVision seems to forcibly forward the user within the prototype which leads to forwarding the top level navigation (so the browser displaying the html file with the video and the iFrame).
3. Using the sandbox attribute to prohibit forwarding works out - but results in the prototype not working anymore. (Loading won't complete).
4. Just forwarding the User to InVision as soon as the Video is clicked works out - but then the prototype is loaded which takes at least around 20s, crushing the users experience.

Besides the obvious of "not using InVision" any clever hacks out there?

Answer (score 0):

I just recreated a prototype with roundabout 100 screens in Proto.io, having the video in front. Works like a charm.